# Column Color formatting based on condition

Tags: sharepoint-online, json

I have a small requirement which can be fulfilled through JSON column formatting but I do not not know how to go about it.
Currently I have  three columns 
1. Consumed quantity : 12(example value)
2. Returned value : say 10(example value)
3. Returned status( calculated value) : 12-10 = 2

Now what I want is to highlight the returned status green when the difference equals 0 and if it is greater than that then it should display Color red.

If you do know please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Is it for SharePoint Online or On-Prem? Do want to modify the list view rendering?

Comment: SharePoint online

Comment: yes it is for list view rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could then try the Client Side Rendering to achieve your goal, or you can try the column formatting option available with Column in the list settings.

Ref
[Column Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

[Client Side Rendering Ref 1](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

[Client Side Rendering Ref 2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

[How To Use Client Side Rendering](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/modify-sharepoint-list-view-using-client-side-rendering-and-jslink/)

[Similar question on stackoverflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241178/how-to-color-code-the-sharepoint-list-column-value-based-on-a-condition/241180#241180)

```
 (function () {

        var statusFieldCtx = {};
        statusFieldCtx.Templates = {};
        statusFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
            "Returned status": {
                "View": StatusFieldViewTemplate
            }
        };

        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldCtx);
    })();

    function StatusFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {



        if (ctx.CurrentItem.Returned status==0)
        {
            return "<div style="color:Green">"+ctx.CurrentItem.Returned status+"/div>";
        }
        else
        {
            return "<div style="color:red">"+ctx.CurrentItem.Returned status+"/div>";
        }
}
```

All the best!!!