# Color code the SharePoint list column value based on a condition?

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-side-rendering

I know this question has been asked and answered but I am new to CSR and I do not even know how to begin to implement this solution.  I have tried to use the solution at this link with no success.

[How to color code the SharePoint list column value based on a condition?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241178/how-to-color-code-the-)
sharepoint-list-column-value-based-on-a-condition

What I want to do is compare Plan vs Actual in a field in SharePoint.  If we exceed the plan it turns green if not it turns red.  I dont want to use the column formatting because I do not want to display an extra column in the view and that only works when the column is included. I would really appreciate some help on this.

Comment: Are you using modern or classic experience? Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380)

Comment: I have tried in both and it is not working in either i think i am missing a step somewhere

Comment: Post the steps you did by editing your question.

Comment: I am following the steps exactly as listed in the link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

The following example for your reference.

1.Create a custom list, add number fields "Plan" and "Actual".

2.Add some data to the list.

If use the Classic UI, we can add the following code into a script editor web part in list view to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () { 
    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var fieldContext = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    fieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Actual": { "View": fieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function fieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var plan = ctx.CurrentItem.Plan;
    var actual = ctx.CurrentItem.Actual;
    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    if(actual>=plan){
        return "<span style='color : green'>" + actual + "</span>";
    }else {
        return "<span style='color : red'>" + actual + "</span>";
    }
}
</script>
```

[image]

If use the Modern UI, we need use column formatting to achieve it.

```
{
   "$schema": 
   "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "debugMode": true,
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
       "color": "=if(@currentField>=[$Plan], 'green', 'red'",
       "padding-top":"11px"
   }
}
```

[image]